# Generating thumbnails for webp file format

Tags: go, webp

The following code is to create a thumbnail using `github.com/disintegration/imaging` package
works well for typical image format like jpeg, but it does not work well for `webp` file format.

I got error`imaging: unsupported image format` with the code below.

Is there a more robust way to generate thumbnails for typical image types (jpg, gif, tiff, bmp, etc.) and webp?

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/disintegration/imaging"
    "github.com/chai2010/webp"
    "io/ioutil"
)

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340751/webp-encoder-decoder-in-go
func main() {
    //img, _ := imaging.Open("ml/input/apple.jpg")

    // Load webp
    data, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("ml/input/waterski2.webp")
    // Decode webp
    img, _ := webp.Decode(bytes.NewReader(data))
    //Create thumbnail
    dstImage := imaging.Thumbnail(img, 400, 400, imaging.Lanczos)

    err1:=imaging.Save(dstImage, "ml/output/waterski2.webp")
    if err1!=nil{
        fmt.Println(err1)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. You'll obviously need a library that supports the format(s) you wish to use, and/or do a conversion.

Comment: You are getting the error when you are trying to save the thumbnail? At least this is what I have deduced. On the other hand checking the packages you shouldn't have to receive the above mentioned error message since the `webp.Decode` method returns an `image.Image`, exactly what the `imaging.Thumbnail` function require.\

Answer (score 0):

I got it works eventually with `webp` `Save` method.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "github.com/chai2010/webp"
    "github.com/disintegration/imaging"
    "io/ioutil"
)

//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8340751/webp-encoder-decoder-in-go
func main() {
    //img, _ := imaging.Open("ml/input/apple.jpg")

    // Load webp
    data, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("ml/input/waterski2.webp")
    // Decode webp
    img, _ := webp.Decode(bytes.NewReader(data))
    //Create thumbnail
    dstImage := imaging.Thumbnail(img, 400, 400, imaging.Lanczos)


    webp.Save("ml/output/waterski2.webp",dstImage,&webp.Options{})

    //err1:=imaging.Save(dstImage, "ml/output/waterski2.webp")
    //if err1!=nil{
    //  fmt.Println(err1)
    //}
}
```